# Do lines in .txt files have exactly 300 characters?

Tags: c, file

I got this code from a question and i don't understand why they have picked exactly 300 for line[300] is it because a line of .txt files  have exactly 300 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 
{
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen("clients.txt", "r");
    if(cfPtr == NULL) 
    {
        puts("The file can't be open");
        return 0;
    }

    char name[11], sex[11], dad[11], mom[11], line[300];
    int age;

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr); //skip the first line
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr))
    {
        if(5 == sscanf(line, "%10s%10s%10d%10s%10s", name, sex, &age, dad, mom))
            printf("%s, %s, %d, %s, %s\n", name, sex, age, dad, mom);
    }

    fclose(cfPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is possibly an arbitrary but "adequate" size. As opposed to the data strings, which are restrictively tight, and unless the data was originally stored with that length restriction, the input will be messed up if the the data is too long.

Comment: Lines don't exist as a special concept in text files on most modern systems. It's just text with line fedd (and/or carriage return) characters to indicate the start of a new line. Whoever wrote this code either knows that every line must be less than 300 characters long, or judged that it's enough.

Comment: according to my understanding of the code it must be the number of the characters in a line of the file

Comment: Each line of the file can be *up to* `298` characters (plus a newline and a string terminator). The requirement is that the buffer is large *enough*. The file data does not have to be that exact length.

Comment: @WeatherVane so it makes sens to  why they have chosen 300 ?

Comment: You'll have to ask them that. If you add up the lengths of the data items that is less. As I wrote, it could just be "enough, generous." Perhaps there is more data on each line that is not being scanned. But you have to pick *some* length and as I also commented it's a bad idea to be tight with string lengths.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such rule or restriction for .txt files.

As for taking 300 as the size of the `line` array and using it in `fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr);`, it is only stating that `fgets` will take atmost 300 character inputs from a line (it can take less if there are less). Most probably, it is taken as an assumption that no line will have more than 300 characters so this is just an upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), cfPtr)
```

`fgets` reads in at most one less than `sizeof(line)` (300 bytes) from stream `cfPtr` and stores them into `line`.

The example below maybe help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char line[4]; // string length ups to 3 with this declaration.
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        printf("%s\n",line);
    }
    printf("enter the string: \n");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    printf("string from keyboard %s\n", line);
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The input file and output:

```
$cat input.txt
123456789

./test
123 // print 3 characters not 10 (one for enter character) characters of the line
456
789


enter the string: 
1234567
line from keyboard 123
```

You can see the result. Even you type `1234567` from the keyboard, the string you got is `123` instead of `1234567`.

This is one reason makes `fgets` is better and safer than `gets` when you enter string from `stdin`.